# ccTouchesMoved and selector:@selector(ButtonTapped:)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

Ill try and keep this as simple as possible.

- I have a guy which you drag around the screen
- I have a shoot button which fires bullets

To drag the guy around the screen im using ccTouchesMoved, basically get the users finger movement and set the guy to that place. Done.

I have a button which is a CCMenuItemImage and if it is tapped then is called a selector to run a method. The method simply fires some bullets. Done.

Now my problem is i cant have these two things work at the same time. I would like the player to be able to drag around the guy and shoot at the same time. Im assuming the button is not being tapped becuase the user is touching and dragging around the player.

How can i fix this? Still be able to drag around with one finger and press the shoot button with the other and they both work together?

Comment: Did you enable multitouches in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to implement your fire button using a sprite.  You can handle ccTouchesBegan and ccTouchesEnded to check for a press within the bounds of your button, to swap it with a pressed state (on begin) or to implement the fire action (on end).

In your ccTouchesMoved handler, you can iterate over the set of touches and determine if the touch that moved is the one over the button, or the touch that should change the character position.